# Firefox - extension to get windows username and pass it to a web page.

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm looking to develop a Firefox extension/add-on that would be able to get the windows username and save it as a variable so a webpage could access it. This is for an strictly internal website for validation purposes to give certain permissions for different users. I am planning on using the following snippet

Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment).get('USERNAME')

This approach gives me the correct username in the error console while using the Add-On builder at 
https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/.

I'm not really sure how to go about actually building an add-on that would just do exacly what the error console output does. When I try just adding that code as a variable and installing the add-on, it gives me the error XPI not build. Any Ideas?

Comment: There's already schemes out there, based on the OS user and group policy, that accomplish that. An old one, NTLM, is still around to a degree, as well as Kerberos (both more or less Windows-centric). There are others, too. You might want to look into that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox already has Integrated Authentication built-in (many people don't know that).
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Integrated_Authentication

Here is a Popular Firefox addon that eases the configuration: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/integrated-auth-for-firefox/

Here is some extra explanation:
http://justgeeks.blogspot.nl/2011/01/firefox-supports-integrated-windows.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but, is there a way to get the actual username as a variable in my webpage with this method?

Comment: Not in the way you are currently thinking of (that I know of), sorry. But since you already stated 'strictly internal website', that shouldn't be necessary. However, now you could handle this server-side (and include the username in the specific source you are sending this user) since you already also wanted 'to give certain permissions for different users'.  So it's just another way to get 'the job' done. Good luck!